# Why isn't this program for calculating sine of the input working?

Tags: c

The following is the source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
double x;

clrscr();
printf("Enter angle:");
scanf("%lf",&x);
printf("Sine %lf = %lf",x,sin(x));
getch();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  I suspect you're entering the angle in degree, but `sin` function expects the angle to be in radian (i.e. 180 degrees = pi radians)

Comment: I entered 3.14. Shouldn't that give me an answer of 0? It gave me 0.001593. Is that acceptable?

Comment: 0.001593 looks correct to me. http://www.google.com/search?q=sin(3.14)

Comment: Do you want the input in radians or in degrees?  Your program assumes radians, but you accepted an answer that assumes degrees.  (Either is fine, of course; I suggest specifying it in the prompt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should Work :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

void main()
{
double x;

clrscr();
printf("Enter angle:");
scanf("%lf",&x);
printf("Sine %lf = %lf",x,sin (x*PI/180));
getch();
}
```

Comment: You repeat the OP's error; it's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.  (Compilers may accept `void main()`, but they aren't required to.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is 3 issues with the code:

1. You should convert `x` to radian angle :`sin(x*3.14159265/180.0)`.
2. You should add `\n` : `printf("Sine %lf = %lf\n",x,sin(x*PI 3.14159265/180.0));` Because it flushes output to `stdout`.
3. Maybe you have a compile error with `clrscr()` which is not supportet with currently compilers.

So try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
  double x;
  printf("Enter angle:");
  scanf("%lf",&x);
  printf("Sine %lf = %lf\n",x,sin(x*3.14159265/180.0));
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
*Accuracy of 3.14 is not well*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: PI is **near** to: 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362 ;-)

Comment: This is why your code will give poor answers for input other than `x == 0`

Comment: You're assuming that the input should be in degrees.  That wasn't implied by the original question.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, you are right, but the question dose not say anything about problem. and i assume one or all of those 3 issues may occurs. Also, accepted answer assumed my assumption too.

Comment: @MasoudM.: Yes, but the OP's comment saying he expected sin(3.14) to be 0 implied radians.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I think it was after my answer or maybe i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use ”%f”, not ”%lf".</strike>  And for future reference, please tell us *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: `"%lf"` is the correct specifier for `scanf` for a (pointer to) `double`; `"%f"` is the correct specifier for `printf` for a `double` (or a `float`, which gets automagically converted to `double`).

Comment: Oops, you're right, of course.  I've struck out the incorrect information, and I'll delete this answer later (leaving it here for a while for anyone who might have seen it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more portable version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x;

    printf("Enter angle (in radians): ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    printf("sin %lf = %lf\n", x, sin(x));

    return 0;
}
```

The changes I've made are:

1. Drop `#include <conio.h>` and the calls to `clrscr()` and `getch();`.  These are Windows- (or MS-DOS-) specific.  That's not necesarily to say that you shouldn't use them (they exist for a reason), but you should at least be aware that they make your program less portable than it could be.  (And why do you want to clear the screen anyway?  I might have information there.)
2. Change `void main()` to `int main(void)`.  Compilers are allowed to accept `void main()`, but it's non-portable, and there is *no* good reason to use it rather than the completely portable `int main(void)`.  (Unless you're writing code for an embedded system that doesn't like `int main(void)`, but that's not the case here.)
3. Add `fflush(stdout);` after the prompt.  This may not be necessary, but it's possible that the prompt won't appear without it.  Portability again.
4. Add `return 0;` to the end of the program.  In the 1990 version of the C standard, falling off the end of the `main` function without a return statement returns an undefined status to the environment; in C99, there's an implied `return 0;`, but it doesn't hurt to make it explicit.

As for the behavior of both your original program and this modified one, `sin(3.14)` *is* approximately 0.001593.  But even if you had entered a more precise value of pi, `sin(x)` *still* wouldn't give you exactly 0.0, because floating-point cannot represent the value of pi exactly.  If you show the result with more precision, you'll see that `sin(3.14159265358979323846264)` comes out to something like `0.00000000000000012246063538223772`.

Finally, the purpose of your `getch()` call is to make the program wait for you to press a key before it terminates (and, presumably, the window in which the output appears vanishes).  That's typically needed for Windows-style IDE environments, but if you run the program from a command prompt it's unnecessary.  Again, I'm not telling you not to call `getch()`, just that you don't necessarily need it.