# to print the sin values table for 0 to 90 degrees in C language

Tags: c, math

the following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//to use 'sin()' function

#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double i=0;

    //printing the values of sine table 
    printf("SINE TABLE :\n\n");
    while(i<=90){
        printf("sin(%.0lf)=%lf\n",i,sin(i));
        i+=15;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I am getting this ouput:

```
SINE TABLE :

sin(0)=0.000000  
sin(15)=0.650288 
sin(30)=-0.988032
sin(45)=0.850904
sin(60)=-0.304811
sin(75)=-0.387782
sin(90)=0.893997
```

but this table is wrong when I checked it with the standard table. I want this answer:

```
SINE TABLE :

sin(0)=0.000000  
sin(15)=0.258819 
sin(30)=0.500000
sin(45)=0.707107
sin(60)=0.866025
sin(75)=0.965926
sin(90)=1.000000
```

what changes should I have to do ?

Comment: The angles for [`sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin) (and all trigonometric functions) are in ***radians***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't this program for calculating sine of the input working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785764/why-isnt-this-program-for-calculating-sine-of-the-input-working)

Comment: duplicates: [sin function not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14583297/995714), [Why isn't this program for calculating sine of the input working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7785764/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C's trigonometry functions work with **radians** - you are using degrees.

Convert your radians to degrees and you should get the results you want:

`i * M_PI / 180.0`

---

On the off chance that you're running on a system where `M_PI` isn't defined in `math.h` - define it yourself:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

Comment: `M_PI` is not a standard C macro.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: @PruthvirajAnuse When you print the value of `i` it *will* be in degrees. But you need to convert it to radians for the *call* to `sin`. As in `sin(i * 3.1415 / 180.0)`

Comment: @user3386109 If `M_PI` isn't defined, define it yourself with a suitable value.

Comment: @PruthvirajAnuse That's not how sin works mathematically - its input is an **angle** (in e.g. degrees or radians), its output is just a dimensionless number, no units.

Comment: If M_PI is not predefined, I would calculate M_PI once by `4 * atan(1)` and use that. It is far too easy to use a wrong value. Many years ago I knew a student using about 20 random digits "because that's what I remember". The third digit was wrong already.

Comment: That's why I wrote "once", for example as `static const double M_PI = 4 * atan(1);`. If necessary, make it a global variable.

Comment: not only C but almost all languages and scientific calculators use radian instead of degree. @user3386109 use `std::numbers::pi` in C++20